# Could not install scipy library and use from scipy.optimize import fsolve

Tags: python, macos, scipy, pip

I installed python 2.7.14 on Macos from the official 64 bit installer.
I can install numpy, matplotlib and some other packages easily using pip.
However, when I installed scipy and try to use it I got errors.

Installation [instructions](https://www.scipy.org/install.html):

```
python --version # 2.7.14
python -m pip install --user numpy scipy
```

### The error log produced is following

```
Bhishan:python
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 12:01:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from scipy.optimize import fsolve
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/poudel/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scipy/optimize/__init__.py", line 240, in <module>
    from .optimize import *
  File "/Users/poudel/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .linesearch import (line_search_wolfe1, line_search_wolfe2,
  File "/Users/poudel/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scipy.optimize import minpack2
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/poudel/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack2.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___addtf3
  Referenced from: /Users/poudel/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scipy/optimize/../.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Users/poudel/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scipy/optimize/../.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib
```

Platform: OSX yosemite 10.10.5

**Update**

```
pip list # has scipy
import scipy # gives no error
from scipy.optimize import fsolve # gives error
```

Comment: Sounds like some dependencies were not installed properly, or are expected to already live on your machine. Also possible that they exist but are out of date.

Comment: Possible dupliucate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881512/5658350

Comment: @DhiaTN that question was error using virtualevn, and i am installing directly. That did not solved my problem, thanks for the link.

Comment: Is there no system package? Can't you use anaconda? I would prefer anything to pip-based installs.

Comment: @sascha I got the same problem with conda also. I had tried anaconda python3.

Comment: The above is not enough to debug this. We don't know how you setup anaconda for example and also not how you did install scipy's external needs (a lot!). Read also [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/3455), which links to one of the big 5 of those external software packages needed: Fortran-compiler, (C, C++, BLAS, LAPACK).

Comment: @sascha, I looked at the issue, the problem was with conda, here i am installing using pip.

Comment: And you can't make out the connection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161220/discussion-between-astro123-and-sascha).